# Market index analysis and techniques

Tags: stocks, stock-exchanges, stock-analysis

**how can i determine market indexes ups and downs in stock market.**
*mean that when will market green and when would be red.*
is trade-volume affect the market index rate?
any analysis or techniques.

Comment: You can't, reliably.

Comment: If there was somebody who could do that, he would be the richest person in this world. And Bill Gates is a techie.

Comment: i don't that exectly rate book near it

Comment: @mr.fahad, your comment does not make sense. Could you please reword it?

Answer (score 1):

Volume and prices are affected together by how folks feel about the stock; there is no direct relationship between them.

There are no simple analysis techniques that work.

Some would argue strongly that there are few complex analysis techniques that work either, and that for anyone but full-time professionals. And there isn't clear evidence that the full-time professionals do sufficiently better than index funds to justify their fees.

For most folks, the best bet is to diversify, using low-overhead index funds, and simply ride with the market rather than trying to beat it.